# How can I make my Discord bot take a response/second event after it has already received a command?

Tags: java, bots, discord

I am working on a discord bot in IntelliJ using Gradle that takes two choices and allows others to vote. However, I can't find a way to make it listen to the vote choice after the vote command has already been used.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws LoginException {
    JDABuilder builder = new JDABuilder(AccountType.BOT);
    String token = "bot token";
    builder.setToken(token);
    builder.addEventListener(new Main());
    builder.buildAsync();


}

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent event) {
    System.out.println("We received a message from " +
            event.getAuthor().getName() + ": " +
            event.getMessage().getContentDisplay()
    );
    if (event.getMessage().getContentRaw().equals("vote uwu")) {
        event.getJDA().addEventListener();
        int choice1 = (int) (Math.random() * 6);
        int choice2 = (int) (Math.random() * 6);
        while (choice2 == choice1) {
            choice2 = (int) (Math.random() * 6);
        }

        event.getChannel().sendMessage("1 - " + choices[choice1][0] + " | 2 - " + choices[choice2][0]).queue();
```

Here it messages the two choices and to press type 1 or 2 to vote. I can't seem to get the vote with this code that follows it because the scores remain the same when printed out and I do not see the vote confirmed message.

```
if (event.getMessage().getContentRaw().equals("1")) {
                choices[choice1][1] = Integer.toString((Integer.parseInt(choices[choice1][1]) + 2));
                choices[choice2][1] = Integer.toString((Integer.parseInt(choices[choice2][1]) - 1));
                event.getChannel().sendMessage("vote counted").queue();
            }
            else if (event.getMessage().getContentRaw().equals("2")) {
                choices[choice2][1] = Integer.toString((Integer.parseInt(choices[choice2][1]) + 2));
                choices[choice1][1] = Integer.toString((Integer.parseInt(choices[choice1][1]) - 1));
                event.getChannel().sendMessage("vote counted").queue();
            }
```

I am assuming I can't use "event" from the MessageReceivedEvent argument again, so how would I approach this?

Comment: The event.getJDA().addEventListener(); after the first if statement was an attempt but I did not get anywhere with that, forgot to remove.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a Discord Bot wait for a specific user to send a message with JDA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54491660/how-to-make-a-discord-bot-wait-for-a-specific-user-to-send-a-message-with-jda)