# How do i exit from a method and run another when a condition is triggered, JDA discord wrappper

Tags: methods, discord-jda

```
public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent event) {
    String[] messagelements = event.getMessage().getContentRaw().split("\\s+");
    if (event.getMessage().getContentRaw().equalsIgnoreCase("what is the number beside " + wordanswer) && event.getAuthor().isBot()){
        time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while (System.currentTimeMillis() -  time <= 8000){
            if (answered.equalsIgnoreCase("answered")) {
                return;
            }else {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        if (answered.equalsIgnoreCase("notanswered")){
            event.getChannel().sendMessage("times up").queue();
        }

    }
}
public void onMessageReactionAdd (MessageReactionAddEvent event) {
    Thread.currentThread().setPriority(10);
    if (event.getUser().equals(worker)) {
        if (answered.equalsIgnoreCase("notanswered")){
            if (event.getReactionEmote().getName().equalsIgnoreCase(emoteanswer)){
                event.getChannel().sendMessage("Correct!").queue();
            }
            else{
                event.getChannel().sendMessage("Wrong").queue();
            }
            answered = "answered";
        }
    }
}
```

the variable answered is to check if the user has already answered the question. However, when my timer starts, it does not detect any activity from the the onMessageReactionAdd and only reacts to it after the timer ends in which "times up" will always be sent then the Wrong/Correct option will then be sent. How do i run both methods simultanously or stop a method and run another when a condition happens. (note that the reaction is the user answer). The timer gives a time limit on the answering the qn and the player will be wrong if they fail to answer within the time limit. Some people suggested using a new thread but i haven’t mastered java and need some help doing that

Comment: You could use either of these: - [Use an EventWaiter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64414297/13210204) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54491660/how-to-make-a-discord-bot-wait-for-a-specific-user-to-send-a-message-with-jda

Answer (score 0):

[You could use either an eventwaiter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64414297/13210204), [or create a response based on a state-machine (Credits to Minn for posthing this)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54492973/13210204)

Depending on your use case, this will differ on how you're going to use it.